# Slack API call to postMessage not working

Tags: google-apps-script, slack-api, urlfetch

I'm just trying to make a simple postMessage call from a google apps script with an image attached, but I get the following response:

```
"{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_arg_name"}"
```

Here is the function that creates the payload:

```
function getPostMessagePayload(fileUrl) {
  var content = {
    "channel":"#data-vis",
    "token": ACCESS_TOKEN,
    "text":"Chart update:",
    "attachments": [
      {
        "title": "Chart",
        "fallback": "Fallback",
        "text": "Testing chart",
        "image_url": fileUrl
      }
    ]
  };
  return content;
}
```

And here is where I make the request:

```
var POST_MESSAGE_ENDPOINT = 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage';

function performPostMessage(payload) {
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    POST_MESSAGE_ENDPOINT,
    {
      method: "post",
      payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    }).getContentText();
  return res;
}
```

It's impossible to tell what the actual problem is. I've tried making my token obviously incorrect, the URL obviously incorrect, and deleting/adding random args and it gives the same response every time.

When I use the webhook to do this rather than the API, it works fine.

My app has the following permissions in Slack:

```
chat:write:bot

incoming-webhook
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

You are sending a `JSON` object as payload with your POST request, whilst the `contentType` parameter of the `fetch()` method is defaulted to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

**Solution 1**

In addition to `JSON.stringify()`, to ensure the payload is sent correctly, wrap it in an `encodeURIComponent()` built-in function. If the issue persists, continue to solution 2.

**Update to solution 1**

Nearly forgot how `fetch()` method treats objects passed to payload with default `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. **Remove the JSON.stringify()** entirely (and add `encodeURI()` / `encodeURIComponent()` if needed).

**Solution 2**

Slack API supports `application/json` content type of POST requests. In your case it might be easier to send the request with `contentType` parameter set to `application.json` (note that you will have to move authorization from payload to `headers`):

```
//fetch part;
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
POST_MESSAGE_ENDPOINT,
{
  method             : 'post',
  contentType        : 'application/json',
  headers            : {
    Authorization : 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN
  },
  payload            : JSON.stringify(payload),
  muteHttpExceptions : true,
})

//payload part;
var payload = {
  "channel"     : "#data-vis",
  "text"        : "Chart update:",
  "attachments" : [
    {
      "title"     : "Chart",
      "fallback"  : "Fallback",
      "text"      : "Testing chart",
      "image_url" : fileUrl
    }
  ]      
};
```

**Useful links**

1. `fetch()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object));
2. `postMessage` method [reference](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) (Slack API);

Comment: Solution 1 did not work, but solution 2 did the trick! Thanks.

Comment: Hi, @Slims! Glad it worked (in fact, Slack even suggests you use the application/json at all times). As for the URL encoding, seems like it should work, I will check what's wrong and will update the answer if I find anything

Comment: @Slims, my bad, I forgot that `fetch()` method doesn't require additional modifications on object passed as payload (I suppose it performs its own) - just pass valid JSON as is and you should be fine (though `application/json` content type is still preferable)